# nice menus - how can I keep all sub-menu expanded in my <front> page?

Tags: routes, javascript

On my front page, I want to have my sub-menus expanded and have them to act as it should on other pages.

I'm using the Nice menus module.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand "have them to act as it should on other pages". Please try to re-phrase.

Comment: I want them all expanded on the front page but I want them hidden until hovered in other pages (as it should)

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block).
Duplicate the menu with the children already expanded and then style it as the other one.